# How to manage(reuse, close) multiple connections using NestJs and Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I need to implement dynamic connections in a Nestjs application.

https://github.com/AgusRdz/multitenant_demo

Currently, connections are created from the data contained in the jwt token that has the id of the company where the user is, with this, we can access the database name and open the connection, something like this:

```
export const dbClient = async (dbname: string) => {
  try {
    const sequelize =
      new Sequelize(
        `company_${dbname}`,
        config().database.user,
        config().database.pass, {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        port: config().database.port,
        replication: {
          write: {
            host: config().database.host,
            port: config().database.port,
          },
          read: [{
            host: config().database.hostRead,
            port: config().database.port,
          }]
        },
        pool: {
          max: 50,
          idle: 30000
        },
        define: {
          timestamps: false,
          // freezeTableName: true
        },
      });
    sequelize.addModels([**Entities**]);
    await sequelize.sync();
    return sequelize;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The idea would be for each user to have access to certain databases and for each request my application would direct him to the database he should access. I would like to implement something similar to the application below, but using Sequelize and Nestjs:

https://github.com/AgusRdz/multitenant_demo

Comment: If you are going to be using JS based tools and want to store the data in js format instead of row, column format, MongoDB might be a better fit for this type of project than MYSQL.

Comment: Side note, Stack Overflow is for fixing problems in code, not for designing them from scratch.  So if you attempt to build this software and get stuck, post the error message and the line of code causing the issue, and then someone on this website can help you out.